# Password protecting an Excel file created using write.xlsx in R with openxlsx

Tags: r, excel, password-protection, openxlsx

I want to password protect a large number of .xslx files I'm creating using a particular workflow. The workflow is simple and relies on having a named list of smaller data frames that I write using the `write.xlsx` command from `openxlsx` in R. Is there a solution to password protecting these files with `protectWorkbook` using a similar workflow? Thank you.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(openxlsx)


## Create reprex using diamonds

df_ls <- diamonds %>% 
  select_if(is.ordered) %>% 
  gather(key, value) %>% 
  split(.$key)
#> Warning: attributes are not identical across measure variables;
#> they will be dropped



## I like to use lists to write to .xlsx
## because write.xlsx creates each object 
## in the list as its own sheet and names
## it using the list names.


.path <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")

write.xlsx(df_ls, file = .path)


## I want to password protect this file(s)

map(.path, ~{protectWorkbook(.x, protect = TRUE, password = "random-password")})

# Error in protectWorkbook(.x, protect = TRUE, password = "random-password") : 
#   First argument must be a Workbook.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a workbook object first as I think that is what the error is indicating. The write.xlsx isn't recognized as a workbook object and that is required for the protectWorkbook argument.

```
df_ls <- diamonds %>% 
  select_if(is.ordered) %>% 
  gather(key, value) %>% 
  split(.$key)

wb = createWorkbook()

lapply(seq_along(df_ls), function(i){
  addWorksheet(wb=wb, sheetName = names(df_ls[i])) #Add each sheet
  writeData(wb, sheet = i, df_ls[[i]])       #Add data to each sheet
  protectWorksheet(wb, sheet = i, protect = TRUE, password = "Password") #Protect each sheet
  })

saveWorkbook(wb, "example.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can directly pass a workbook object with multiple sheets?